# Using CDF to upper bound MGF

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds, moment-generating-functions

I have some random variable with a complicated but known analytical CDF and I need an upper bound on the MGF. Direct MGF computation is intractable due to the messy nature of the CDF so I was trying to use Markov inequality to try to get some bounds on the MGF but I can only get lower bounds, exactly opposite of what I need!

PS - the random variable is almost surely in $[0,1]$. Is there any other inequality I can use to get an upper bound on the MGF?

Comment: For $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have (with prob 1) $e^{tX} \leq e^t$ so $E[e^{tX}]\leq e^t$.

Comment: @Michael that bound is unfortunately too weak for me!

Comment: Then try $$E[e^{tX}] \leq e^{t/2}P[X\leq 1/2] + E[e^{tX}|X\in (1/2, 1]]P[X \in (1/2,1]]$$ =)